# Error al insertar nodo en archivo xml

Tags: c#, json, .net, xml, nodos

Tengo un nuevo registro en formato json que quiero añadir a mi archivo xml. Lo primero que hago es convertirlo a xml e intento insertarlo en el archivo pero me da error en la línea del InsertAfter:

"System.InvalidOperationException: No se puede insertar el nodo especificado como elemento secundario válido de este nodo, porque el nodo especificado es incorrecto.
   en System.Xml.XmlNode.InsertAfter(XmlNode newChild, XmlNode refChild)"

Este es el código:

```
    ...

    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.Load(xmlUrl);

    XmlNode root = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;       

    string strJson = "{\r\n   \"CD\": {\r\n      \"TITLE\": \"Still got the blues\",\r\n      \"ARTIST\": \"Gary Moore\",\r\n      \"COUNTRY\": \"UK\",\r\n      \"COMPANY\": \"Virgin records\",\r\n      \"PRICE\": \"10.20\",\r\n      \"YEAR\": \"1990\"\r\n   }\r\n}";

    XmlNode node = JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(strJson);

    root.InsertAfter(node, root.FirstChild);

    ...
```

La estructura del archivo xml es esta:

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<CATALOG>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>Empire Burlesque</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1985</YEAR>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>Hide your heart</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Bonnie Tyler</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>CBS Records</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1988</YEAR>
  </CD>
  ...
  ...
</CATALOG>
```

¿Alguien me puede echar una mano y decirme qué es lo que estoy haciendo mal? ¿Tengo que insertar un XmlNode o un XmlElement? (no entiendo muy bien la diferencia entre ambos :-/ )

Muchas gracias !!!

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con este cambio:

ya que el error que te indica es por tipo, si agregas un try catch en tu código, en el exception veras que el nodo que estas tratanto de agregar viene con tipo document y lo que tu necesitas agregar es un tipo element.

```
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.Load(xmlUrl);

    XmlNode root = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;       

    string strJson = "{\r\n   \"CD\": {\r\n      \"TITLE\": \"Still got the blues\",\r\n      \"ARTIST\": \"Gary Moore\",\r\n      \"COUNTRY\": \"UK\",\r\n      \"COMPANY\": \"Virgin records\",\r\n      \"PRICE\": \"10.20\",\r\n      \"YEAR\": \"1990\"\r\n   }\r\n}";

    XmlNode node =xmlDoc.ImportNode(JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(strJson).DocumentElement,true);

    root.InsertAfter(node, root.FirstChild);
```

Espero te sirva, saludos.